# All Users are not being tracked in Sitecore Analytics

Tags: xdb, configuration, experience-analytics, user-profile

In my project on Sitecore 8.2, I am using Contact Facet to identify users.

Problem Definition:

1. All users are not being tracked, seems some of them are missing in xDB.
2. Seems xDB and Experience Profiles are not in sync. Some users entries were in xDB but still not reflected in experience profile.

What are the possible reasons?

Let me know if more information is needed on this.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using? Are the users not reflected in Experience Profile are anonymous visitors?

Comment: I am using Sitecore 8.2. Both anonymous and identified users and reflected in experience profile report but data is not accurate. Some time users are tracked and some users are lost.

Comment: Please check your logs because if one of the aggregation pipelines fail, it will not execute the other pipelines

Comment: there are multiple reasons to get report database out of sync with xDB. rebuilding the reporting databse will help.

Answer (score 1):

This requires you to debug through the whole Sitecore--> xDB --> Aggregation pipeline--> reporting databases --> Sitecore_Analytics_Index.

Please ensure the below:

1. CD is recording the interactions correctly in xDB- MongoDB.
2. CM / Processing server is picking up the interactions to be processed/aggregated
3. Your Aggregation processors are not throwing any exceptions
4. Also check the the tables in reporting databases, they have correct data
5. Your experience profile report depends on sitecore_analytics_index and the reporting database.

Let us know if you can check on the above.